# XAMPP環境で、MySQLに接続しようとしたところ、MariaDBに接続された

Tags: mysql, command-line, xampp, mariadb

```
$ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

を打つと、

```
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 5
Server version: 10.1.34-MariaDB Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

となり、

```
MariaDB [(none)]> status
```

MariaDBに繋がってしまいます。

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql
```

を開くと、

```
$ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql ; exit;
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 7
Server version: 10.1.34-MariaDB Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

とMariaDBになっています。

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

と打つと、

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

となり、パスワードさえ聞かれません。

```
$ mysql
```

と打っても

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

となります。
XAMPPをインストールしてから設定は何も変えていません。
どのように操作をしたらMariaDBではなくmysqlに接続できるのでしょうか。
他に必要な情報があれば提示します。
お手数おかけしますがご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

```
環境
macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
xampp-osx-7.2.8
```

Comment: 現在のXAMPPは、DBとしてMySQLではなくMariaDBをパッケージングしています。XAMPPとは別にMySQLをインストールすることはできるでしょうが、せっかくオールインワンのパッケージになっているXAMPPを使う意義は大きく薄れてしまうでしょう。MariaDBはMySQLとの互換性を意識して開発されているため、XAMPPでは過去のスクリプトなどと互換性を持たせるために`mysql`コマンドがMariaDBを呼び出すようになっているのでしょう。なにか絶対にMySQLでないといけないような事情があるのでしょうか?

Comment: 質問の前に、まずはweb検索(下調べ)することも大事です。

Comment: 質問文で伏せ字にされている箇所はPC名とユーザ名だと思いますが、ここは伏せ字にするより削除して`$`以降を書いてもらった方が見やすいです。

Comment: XAMPPはデフォルトでMariaDBってだけの話なんですね。sqlを別でインストールします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mariaDBはMySQL(のソースコード)を元にしたデータベースです。細かな違いはありますが、基本的にはMySQLとコマンドや設定ファイルが同じです。

単に`mysql`と打っても「コマンドが見つからない」となるのはPATHが通っていないからで、以下のコマンドを実行してから`mysql`コマンドを試してください。

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

なお、上記の設定は一時的なものなので、実際には`.bashrc`に設定を追加することになります。

参考：
[PATHを通すために環境変数の設定を理解する (Mac OS X)](https://qiita.com/soarflat/items/d5015bec37f8a8254380)

もちろんMySQLをインストールすることもできますが、既に利用しているXAMPPに同梱のmariaDBとの競合やデータ移行をどうするかなど別の問題(質問)を引き起こす可能性があるので、あまりおすすめしません。